# How do I delete a hard drive partition/merge it with the main one?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I made a partition to install another OS. But I want to get rid of it now. How do I do it safely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Windows Vista or Windows 7, go to `Disk Management`, and simply delete the partition you do not need, then extend your existing one to take over the space.

If you are using Windows XP, the best bet is to use [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net) to do the same operation.

If you need any help on any of these stages, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

- in windows 7 , you can do it like this

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/

Download Disk Director Home Plus

http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, but best safe (and completely FREE) partitioning product I have used for ANY windows system, is EASUS http://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizard/download.htm