# Transfer hard drive space from one partition to the other

Tags: windows, partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free Software for Partition Manager](https://superuser.com/questions/12386/free-software-for-partition-manager)
>   [How do I delete a hard drive partition/merge it with the main one?](https://superuser.com/questions/187465/how-do-i-delete-a-hard-drive-partition-merge-it-with-the-main-one)

I have a 500 GB SATA hard drive.

The drive is partitioned as:

- 250 GB C Drive
- 250 GB F Drive

Why this was done, I'll never know. My question is: Can I transfer 200 GB from my F drive, back to my C drive? The F Drive contains 73MB of data. The rest is free.

I am running Windows XP Pro.

Comment: Sure...Just transfer the data then merge the paritions.

Comment: There are many partitioning tools that allow you to merge or resize existing partitions. You just need to be sure to move your data to C, and then merge them, as Ramhound said. Keep a backup just in case.

Comment: Check out [How do I delete a hard drive partition/merge it with the main one?](http://superuser.com/questions/187465/how-do-i-delete-a-hard-drive-partition-merge-it-with-the-main-one)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether specific app recommendations are allowed here, but I recommend using the [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php). As always with such operations, be careful and ensure you have an up-to-date backup of your important data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should ease us partition manager, it is free, reliable and tested by me many times. check it out. thanks.